# My f7/vue radio button is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, html-framework-7

I am using the following code snippet. I have it start up with "medium" Checked. However, if I "check" small or large, it does not uncheck medium. My goal is for one list item to be selected out of the entire group.

```
<f7-list>
      <f7-list-group>
        <f7-list-item title="Font Size" group-title></f7-list-item>
        <f7-list-item radio title="Small" class="Small"></f7-list-item>
        <f7-list-item radio title="Medium" class="Medium" checked></f7-list-item>
        <f7-list-item radio title="Large" class="Large"></f7-list-item>
      </f7-list-group>
 </f7-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for radio inputs to work, plain HTML requires every input to have the same "name" attribute. If you are using VueJS, Vue requires every input to have the same "v-model" attribute. That is what is missing here.

Comment: I am using Vue. v-model attribute did not work; but having the same name attribute did...Thanks